# MySQL NodeJS Error : Cannot enqueue Query after invoking quit using transactions

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, node-modules, restify

I've been implementing MySQL for NodeJS and Restify and everything has worked perfectly in terms of queries. But when I wanted to use the functionality of updating data through transactions I got the following error: **Error: Cannot enqueue Query after invoking quit.**

Here's the trace:

```
(node:10877) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot enqueue Query after invoking quit.
at Protocol._validateEnqueue (/home/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:215:16)
at Protocol._enqueue (/home/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:138:13)
at Connection.query (/home/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:201:25)
at Connection.beginTransaction (/home/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:154:15)
at Promise (/home/app/mysql/repository/ClientDao.ts:56:23)
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at ClientDao.updateIps (/home/app/mysql/repository/ClientDao.ts:55:16)
at /home/app/routes/ips/put.ts:22:31
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at fulfilled (/home/app/routes/ips/put.ts:5:58)
```

And here's the code:

```
this.conn.connect();
return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
        this.conn.beginTransaction( (err) => {
            if(err) {
                reject(err);
                return;
            }
            this.conn.query('UPDATE client SET ips_allowed = ? WHERE id = ?', [ips, client.id], (error, results, fields) => {
                if(error) {
                    return this.conn.rollback(() => reject(error));
                }
                this.conn.commit((error) => {
                    if(error) {
                        return this.conn.rollback(() => reject(error));
                    }
                    this.conn.end();
                });
            });

        });
    });
```

If anyone can help me see the mistake, I'd appreciate it very much. As I said before, it only happens to me with transactions.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by myself, be careful if you are doing previous queries to another one, when you do .end() the mySql.createConnection() carrier object becomes 'Undefined' or 'Null' so it can't connect again until it is created again. I guess it was obvious if the way to implement is not optimal.